# Storybook optional props force undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook

I didn't find any answer that resolve my problem. I'm building a React Storybook with Typescript. With optional props, Storybook addon add an "undefined" option. I put a defaultProps but it doesn't take it. Do you have any solution ?

Component :

```
type IconType = 'outline' | 'solid'

export interface IconProps {
  name: keyof typeof icons
  size?: number
  type?: IconType
  className?: string
  fallback?:
    | boolean
    | React.ReactChild
    | React.ReactFragment
    | React.ReactPortal
    | null
}

const Icon = ({
  name,
  type = 'solid',
  className = '',
  size = 4,
  fallback = null,
}: IconProps): JSX.Element => {
  if (!name) {
    throw new Error("Can't call Icon component without name props")
  }

  const Icon = React.lazy(
    () => import(`../${type}/${icons[name]}`)
  )

  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={fallback}>
      <Icon className={className} style={{width: size, height: size}} />
    </React.Suspense>
  )
}

Icon.defaultProps = {
  type: 'solid',
}

export default Icon
```

Story:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/react'
import Icon, { IconProps } from '.'

export default {
  title: 'Components/Icon',
  component: Icon,
} as Meta

const Template: Story<IconProps> = (args) => <Icon {...args} />

export const Basic = Template.bind({})
Basic.args = {
  name: 'plus',
}
```

It shows me:
[image]

And when I select undefined it doesn't take the defaultProps of Icon

Comment: `when I select undefined`. does it actually set the value to `undefined` or does it set the value to a string of `"undefined"` ?

Comment: undefined, no string

Comment: Try posting a reproducible demo using http://codesandbox.io/

Comment: I tried some debugging with console.log and it seems it gets a string.

Comment: I have this exact problem! going to try and make a demo

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, for me it works fine like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { ComponentStory, ComponentMeta } from '@storybook/react'
import Icon, { IconProps } from '.'

export default {
  title: 'Components/Icon',
  component: Icon,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Icon>

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Icon> = (args: IconProps) => <Icon {...args} />

export const Basic = Template.bind({})
export const BasicArgs: IconProps = {
  name: 'plus',
}
Basic.args = BasicArgs
```

Also when I was trying to export and use the story somewhere else it didn't work because the type was not matching: This I was able to solve it by creating an additional typed object called `BasicArgs` in between and then assigning it to `Basic.args` in your case.

Now you can import it somewhere else and use it just like that:

```
import { Basic, BasicArgs } from './Icon.stories'
    
...  (
       <Basic {...BasicArgs} />
    ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting storybook text controls, it always returns type string and sometimes I need it to be undefined. One workaround I have found is to handle it in the story and override the args.

```
if (args.label?.length === 0) {
    args.label = undefined;
}
```